# Application add to startup ( need administrator rights to start app )

Tags: windows, startup, administrator

I have a C# application and I want to add this application to start-up. I use:

```
 RegistryKey Key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true);
 Key.SetValue("APPName", "C:\\Program Files\\App\AppName.exe");
```

My application need Administrator Right to run, I want a method to register my app or to add to trusted applications.

### Thanks.

Now I'm using:

```
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo(
            Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
        {
            Verb = "runas", // indicates to elevate privileges
        };

        var process = new Process
        {
            EnableRaisingEvents = false, // enable WaitForExit()
            StartInfo = info
        };

        process.Start();
```

For obtain access only for one method, but now I have problem with

```
     unauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
```

I'm trying to create a directory in C:\Program Files.

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

If your using visual studio 2010 or 2012, goto add new item, Application Manifest. 
Change the requestedExecutionLevel to this below:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Now when your application starts it will ask to run in elevated mode.

Another way is to restart the application in elevated mode. For this you don't need the app manifest.

You can read about both these techniques here: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105506/Getting-Elevated-Privileges-on-Demand-using-C

Comment: Thanks, now I'm using:
    var info = new ProcessStartInfo(
            Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
            {
                Verb = "runas", // indicates to elevate privileges
            };

            var process = new Process
            {
                EnableRaisingEvents = false, // enable WaitForExit()
                StartInfo = info
            };

            process.Start();
For obtain access only for one method, but now I have problem with 

         unauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
I'm trying to create a directory in C:\Program Files.

Comment: This is a very general exception meaning you don't have rights to create a directory in program files.